# Java JSON parser failing on native JavaScript call

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

I have a need to parse JSON in Java from a file that we use in the browser, which contains JavaScript.

When the JSON parser gets to the `cb` key, and `location.protocol`, it has an issue and fails.

```
{
    data: {
        data1: {
            plugins: ['voip', 'speed', 'act', 'capacity'],
            last: "~last~",
            unit: "~units~",
            sid: '~sessionid~',
            by: "~by~"
        }
    },
    cb: location.protocol + "//" + location.host,
    thresholds: ['default'],
    calendars: ['default']
}
```

Is there any way in Java or the JSON parser to account for this so I can still access the keys I need?

Comment: The code you presented as JSON seems rather a  JavaScript object definition, rather than valid JSON (which uses double-quotes wrapping keys and does not allow expressions to construct values like `location.protocol + "//" + location.host`. What is your JSON-parser implementation in Java?

Comment: hc_dev is correct.  That is not JSON, and the parser is behaving exactly as it should.  The JSON syntax has a [precise definition](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159.html).

Comment: You need to encode your output as JSON before trying to parse it. This is probably not valid JSON. Do JSON.stringify(obj) in the browser